# RMS value of a function

Tags: python, numpy

Now the full code / questions

I would like to estimate the random fluctuations of the function v - therefore I would like to calculate the RMS value of it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt




def HHmodel(I,length, area):

        v = []
        m = []
        h = []
        z = []
        n = []
        squares = []
        vsquare = (-60)*(-60)
        sumsquares = 0
        rms = []
        a= []
        dt = 0.05
        t = np.linspace(0,100,length)


        #constants
        Cm = area#microFarad
        ENa=50 #miliVolt
        EK=-77  #miliVolt
        El=-54 #miliVolt
        g_Na=120*area #mScm-2
        g_K=36*area #mScm-2
        g_l=0.03*area #mScm-2

        def alphaN(v):
            return 0.01*(v+50)/(1-np.exp(-(v+50)/10))

        def betaN(v):
            return 0.125*np.exp(-(v+60)/80)

        def alphaM(v):
            return 0.1*(v+35)/(1-np.exp(-(v+35)/10))

        def betaM(v):
            return 4.0*np.exp(-0.0556*(v+60))

        def alphaH(v):
            return 0.07*np.exp(-0.05*(v+60))

        def betaH(v):
            return 1/(1+np.exp(-(0.1)*(v+30)))

        #Initialize the voltage and the channels :
        v.append(-60)
        rms.append(1)
        m0 = alphaM(v[0])/(alphaM(v[0])+betaM(v[0]))
        n0 = alphaN(v[0])/(alphaN(v[0])+betaN(v[0]))
        h0 = alphaH(v[0])/(alphaH(v[0])+betaH(v[0]))

        #t.append(0)
        m.append(m0)
        n.append(n0)
        h.append(h0)

        #solving ODE using Euler's method:
        for i in range(1,len(t)):
            m.append(m[i-1] + dt*((alphaM(v[i-1])*(1-m[i-1]))-betaM(v[i-1])*m[i-1]))
            n.append(n[i-1] + dt*((alphaN(v[i-1])*(1-n[i-1]))-betaN(v[i-1])*n[i-1]))
            h.append(h[i-1] + dt*((alphaH(v[i-1])*(1-h[i-1]))-betaH(v[i-1])*h[i-1]))
            gNa = g_Na * h[i-1]*(m[i-1])**3
            gK=g_K*n[i-1]**4
            gl=g_l
            INa = gNa*(v[i-1]-ENa)
            IK = gK*(v[i-1]-EK)
            Il=gl*(v[i-1]-El)
            v.append(v[i-1]+(dt)*((1/Cm)*(I[i-1]-(INa+IK+Il))))
            #v.append(v[i-1]+(dt)*((1/Cm)*(I-(INa+IK+Il))))
        meansquare = np.sqrt((np.square(v).sum()))
        return v,area,meansquare




spikeEvents = []  #timing each spike
length = 1000*5  #the time period

fluctuations = []
output = []



for j in range(1, 10):
    barcode = np.zeros(length)
    noisyI = np.random.normal(0,9,length)
    area = 1.0+0.1*j
    res = HHmodel(noisyI,length,area)
    output.append(res[2])




print('Done.')
```

The goal should be that the fluctuations of v increase in some way with the size of the are a - I was thinking here of the rms amplitude as a reasonable measure

BR

edit:

```
 for i in range(1,len(t)):
            m.append(m[i-1] + dt*((alphaM(v[i-1])*(1-m[i-1]))-betaM(v[i-1])*m[i-1]))
            n.append(n[i-1] + dt*((alphaN(v[i-1])*(1-n[i-1]))-betaN(v[i-1])*n[i-1]))
            h.append(h[i-1] + dt*((alphaH(v[i-1])*(1-h[i-1]))-betaH(v[i-1])*h[i-1]))
            gNa = g_Na * h[i-1]*(m[i-1])**3
            gK=g_K*n[i-1]**4
            gl=g_l
            INa = gNa*(v[i-1]-ENa)
            IK = gK*(v[i-1]-EK)
            Il=gl*(v[i-1]-El)
            v.append(v[i-1]+(dt)*((1/Cm)*(I[i-1]-(INa+IK+Il))))
            z.append(v[i-1]-np.mean(v))
            #v.append(v[i-1]+(dt)*((1/Cm)*(I-(INa+IK+Il))))
        mean = sum(np.square(v))/len(v)
        squared_diffs =[(item-mean)**2 for item in v]
        ms_diff = sum(squared_diffs)/len(squared_diffs)
        rms_diff =np.sqrt(ms_diff)
        return v,area,rms_diff
```

edit2: [image: Plot for j in range(1,10) - blue: rmsvalue as calculated in edit 1, yellow 1/sqrt(j)]
Plot for j in range(1,10) - blue: rmsvalue as calculated in edit 1, yellow 1/sqrt(j)

edit3: [image: Plot for j in range(1,100) - but the "size" of fluctuations should increase, and not decrease and center somewhere]

Plot for j in range(1,100) - but the "size" of fluctuations should increase, and not decrease and center somewhere

Comment: Why are you doing the weird range and -1 on all the indices?

Comment: I can't say too much because I'm not 100% what you would like to achieve. But within your loop ```meansquare``` is being divided by ```len(t)``` despite the fact that the loop does not run up to ```len(t)``` for all iterations but the last.

Comment: If your values are being stored within the list ```v``` I would suggest that you do the squaring outside the loop. So within the loop just append values to ```v``` and then after the loop has terminated you can calculate the sum of squares as ```np.square(v).sum()```, which may help.

Comment: After you have created `v`, then: `rms = np.sqrt(np.mean(v**2))`

Comment: but v**2 is tricky since v is a list?

Comment: I have completely completed the question

Comment: Again, see answer below. You need RMS error with respect to mean calculated for a single area. Then, calculate for several areas and plot to see whether they are correlated. Taking RMS  of ```v``` itself is basically calculating the mean of ```v``` whereas you want the variance or stddev of ```v``` so you need to take RMS of difference from mean.

Comment: And no v^2 for a list is easy: ```squared = [item**2 for item in list]```. Or convert to a numpy array is also easy

Answer (score 1):

A few minor notes:

- So, basically your "function" `v` is a one-timestep discrete evaluation of some function rather than a true function, but that's not really relevant here.
- As indicated by comments above, you should calculate v for all timesteps and aggregate the squared values, then sum them outside of the loop and normalize by dividing by `len(v)`.
- It is also unclear why in iteration `i` you calculate `v[i]` but the corresponding squared value you calculate is `v[i-1]` squared. Should use same index on same loop iteration or you'll likely end up missing an element.

I would say that the reason that the result is not useful is that root-mean square is not really ever used for a function's outputs (RMS in this case is just some sort of less useful mean that gives extra weight to outliers); rather RMS is generally used on the error or variance of that function's outputs. RMS error or variance tells you how far, in the function's original units, does the average function value differ from the average value?). Note that this is only really an imporant metric if you expect the value of v to be constant.

Given all this, it's hard to say from your question what your intention is and what you're actually trying to do with this info so I will guess that what you really care about is how much the value of v is varying from the mean. In this case, you can use RMS difference from mean value of `v` calculated as such:

```
for i in range(1,len(t)):
        #calculate v[i] here, omitted for simplicity

    # get mean value
    mean = sum(squares)/len(squares)

    # you want to get the squared value of the difference, not the value itself
    squared_diffs = [(item - mean)**2 for item in v)]


    # get mean squared diff
    ms_diff = sum(squared_diffs) / len(squared_diffs)

    # return root of mean squared diff
    rms_diff = np.sqrt(ms_diff)

    return v,area,rms_diff
```

Again, this is only useful if you expect the outputs of `v` to be a constant. If not, you would try to fit a different model (linear, quadratic, etc.) to the function and then calculate the RMS error. Question would be much clearer if you indicated goal of this calculation.

Comment: Hi Derek - this Model is called the Hodgkin Huxley Model (used for neuronal simulations) - I want to calculate random ionic current voltage fluctuations (in theory they should be dependent on the surface area of the membrane itself - v is the voltage across the membrane and can be calculated by solving the differential equation in my post. Now I would like to solve the ODE for increasing sizes of the membrane (doing it in the Loop) and want to see that the random fluctuations are increasing.

Comment: Yeah, that's ok. basically, v is a function of time (hence calculating values at various t's) but v is also parameterized by a. So v fluctuates over time. Now, correct me if I am wrong, but what you really care about is the average magnitude **of the fluctuations**, not the average magnitude of v.

Comment: So, the first thing you need to do is, with constant a, once you have calculated v for each timestep, you need to estimate the size of the fluctuation of v at that timestep. Now, thus far I have been assuming that v is centered around some value (the mean), and fluctates both upwards and downwards from this, and you don't care about the sign of v, just the size of the fluctuations. Alternatively, v could have a minimum of 0, and you only care about the magnitude of v above 0. If this is the case just take the mean of v.

Comment: But if this is not the case and you indeed care only about the magnitude of the fluctuations of v, regardless of sign, then you should estimate the fluctuation size at each timestep as the difference between the mean and the value of v at that timestep.

Comment: Hi Derek - thanks for you answer! I am not quite sure what do you mean by "estimate the fluctuation size at each time step between the mean and the value of v at that tilmestep" and yes its about the average magnitude of fluctuations.

Comment: for example I get 5000 values of v within t = np.linspace(0,100,5000) and membrane size 1.5 ; then I want membrane size 2 and also get 5000 values of v again -- now I want to increase the size up to (for instance 20) and see if the fluctuations get bigger

Comment: Yep. You care about fluctuations in v. So, consider two sine waves. ```f1 = sin(t) +5 ``` and ```f2 = 10*sin(t)+5```. Obviously, the fluctuations of f2 are 10 times the size of the fluctations of f1. But the mean of each of these functions is 5. So to get the "size of the fluctuations", you need to take the difference between f1 and the mean of f1, and the difference between f2 and the mean of f2, and then take the RMS of those values. Otherwise, the mean of v will bias your results.

Comment: Derek: 
So you mean I should subtract the mean of the entire list from each individual list entry?

Comment: Derek I have edited the original post and included your suggestion - do you mean the way i did it?

Comment: And then I would like to plot it depending on the area and not depending on the time - do you think plt.plot (rmsvalue, area) would be possible here, or would there be a scaling problem here?

Comment: I think I do not get the "size of fluctuations" now - sorry but its so tricky working on my tablet ... many thanks for thinking and reading :)

Comment: if I do it according to this format, the fluctuations will level off around the mean ...

Comment: Derek? are you still out there? :)

Comment: I'm not really sure what else to say, don't know what you mean by "fluctuations level off around the mean". Post some plots of v vs. t for various areas and the associated RMS value you get for each so I have some idea how to help you

Comment: Hi Derek - i have added two plots :)

Comment: Just because you expect the "size of fluctuations" to increase with increasing a or whatever it is that you expect, doesn't mean that it's going to. There may be a problem with the way you are calculating your metric, or there may be a fundamental flaw in the model itself or in your reasoning about the model.

Comment: yes you are right - so you don't see some sort of "coding" error ? Can you think of another useful metric for the size of the fluctuations? but just think: why should more "noise" sources lead to smaller fluctuations in absolute terms?

Comment: For one, the "sources of noise" may also have effects that increase the stability of v. Consider that maintaining the same voltage across a greater surface area may require greater total charge, such that the fluctuations in charge relative to the total charge are relatively smaller. I'm not saying this is correct, I'm just suggesting that if you make assumptions about what output should look like and then try to get your simulations to match up, you may never get the results you are looking for and even if you do they may not be informative.

Comment: that's a good point - i will also increase the noise input according to the area

Comment: Hello Derek, I thought about it again: the sum of the deviations from the mean should increase with the area - the amplitude of the oscillations of the difference from the mean .. does that make sense for you?